# Akka http - SSE - Not receiving streaming Json response

Tags: akka-http

I am playing with Server Sent Events to get updates from akka-http v2.4.11 based micro-service. I am using [akka-sse](https://github.com/hseeberger/akka-sse). For some reason, I am not receiving any updates on my Javascript front-end. However, as soon as, I terminate or kill the server process, I get some of the messages in the front-end. My code looks like this:

```
val start = ByteString.empty
val sep = ByteString("\n")
val end = ByteString.empty

import Fill._
implicit val jsonStreamingSupport: JsonEntityStreamingSupport = 
      EntityStreamingSupport.json()
                            .withFramingRenderer(Flow[ByteString].intersperse(start, 
                                                                              sep, 
                                                                              end))

import de.heikoseeberger.akkasse.EventStreamMarshalling._

def routes: Route = pathPrefix("subscribe") {
  path("fills") {
    get {
      complete {
        Source.actorPublisher[Fill](FillProvider())
              .map(fill ⇒ sse(fill))
              .keepAlive(1.second, () ⇒ ServerSentEvent.heartbeat)
      }
    }
 }
}

def sse[T: ClassTag](obj: T)(implicit w: JsonWriter[T]): ServerSentEvent = {
  ServerSentEvent(data = w.write(obj).compactPrint, 
                  eventType = classTag[T].runtimeClass.getSimpleName)
}
```

Any pointers what I can be doing wrong? To me, it seems that I am following every instructions as mentioned [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.11/scala/http/routing-dsl/source-streaming-support.html#Responding_with_JSON_Streams)